# Network listener doesnt get points

Tags: android

I have a problem with my locationListener.

This is my "MyLocationListenerNetWork":

```
public class MyLocationListenerNetwork implements LocationListener {

    public MyLocationListenerNetwork(){
        super();
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location loc) {
        if(loc!=null){

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String pDisabled) {
            }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String pEnabled) {
        }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    }
}
```

The point is that, i have a Service, where i want to "request" the listener to take the network points. I do like this in my onCreate()

```
LocationManager lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
            locationListenerNetwork = new MyLocationListenerNetwork();
            if(locationListenerNetwork!=null)
                lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 
                        0, 0, locationListenerNetwork);
```

It gets points without problems. The problem is that it consume a lot of battery, if I let it on all the time, it consume 30-40% of the battery. I would like to turn it on only a period of time.
That´s why inside the service i have a Thread, and inside this thread, i turn on the listener only for a period of time(5minutes), but when I do that, the listener doesn´t retrieve any point....

Anyone knows why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think in your **reQuestLocationUpdates** method check the parameters, **minTime**

Is what you needed, **So just mentioned location request time in minTime parameter So you don't need a Thread for this**..

```
public void requestLocationUpdates (String provider, long minTime, float minDistance, LocationListener listener)
```

Since: API Level 1

Registers the current activity to be notified periodically by the named provider. Periodically, the supplied LocationListener will be called with the current Location or with status updates.

It may take a while to receive the most recent location. If an immediate location is required, applications may use the getLastKnownLocation(String) method.

In case the provider is disabled by the user, updates will stop, and the onProviderDisabled(String) method will be called. As soon as the provider is enabled again, the onProviderEnabled(String) method will be called and location updates will start again.

**The frequency of notification may be controlled using the minTime and minDistance parameters. If minTime is greater than 0, the LocationManager could potentially rest for minTime milliseconds between location updates to conserve power. If minDistance is greater than 0, a location will only be broadcasted if the device moves by minDistance meters. To obtain notifications as frequently as possible, set both parameters to 0.**

**Background services should be careful about setting a sufficiently high minTime so that the device doesn't consume too much power by keeping the GPS or wireless radios on all the time. In particular, values under 60000ms are not recommended.**

The calling thread must be a Looper thread such as the main thread of the calling Activity.

**Parameters**

**provider**    the name of the provider with which to register

**minTime** the minimum time interval for notifications, in milliseconds. This field is only used as a hint to conserve power, and actual time between location updates may be greater or lesser than this value.

**minDistance** the minimum distance interval for notifications, in meters

**listener**    a {#link LocationListener} whose onLocationChanged(Location) method will be called for each location update

**EDIT:**

GPS services are usually memory hungry. Do you need GPS services or just looking for location updates? Android comes with a good startup doco for location based services . http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/obtaining-user-location.html
Try following the steps in this doco to find best user location.

Make sure to stop listening for updates at the appropriate time. Users will not be happy that one app tries to drain the battery even when it is not running.

Try making the app as a background task.. i.e a Service or BroadcastReceiver

Comment: Thank you, but anyway it is not working. I am trying to do what you said, but the result is the same. The application consume the same ammount of energy.....Btw, I put a "stop point" on the "onLocationChanged" method, and it still takes points every seconds(even when i put the requestUpdates of the listener to take in 60000ms.......). I don´t know if this is a problem of the API of Android or it is just that I am not using it correctly. Thank you anyway for your help!

Comment: not working Means? Have you looked at the url in my answer's edit portion.

Comment: Thanks again. After using the locationListener inside the onCreate, it works. And, well......don´t know why, but whatever the change I do on the requestLocationUpdates(minDistance, minTime), it doesnt change anything....It keeps updating the location every time....(i tried by putting minDistance=200000 and minTime=100000 and it keeps taking the position every seconds....)